# How does matplotlib set its y-axis values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm wondering about the intuition behind matplotlib y-axis values and how they are set. When I run the code below, it returns nice, evenly spaced y-axis values. Does anyone know the approach matplotlib use and how these values are determined?

At best, if anyone could help me provide an example of Python code how to replicate the y-axis values, without plotting the graph.

Thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

dims = 1
step_n = 2000
step_set = [-1, 0, 1]
origin = np.zeros((1,dims))
random.seed(30)
step_shape = (step_n,dims)
steps = np.random.choice(a=step_set, size=step_shape)
path = np.concatenate([origin, steps]).cumsum(0)
plt.plot(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's open source, you can look it up.  You decide roughly how many ticks you want.  Then, you divide the total range by that many ticks (plus slop to make a pretty margin).  Then, you need to round it to a nice number.  Taking int(log10) of the tick value gets you close, but if the fractional part of the log is close to 0.3 (which is log10(5)), then you can multiply the step size by 5.  Once you have the step size, you just find the multiples of that value from the min to the max.  This is the approximate idea:

```
mmax = path.max() * 1.1
mmin = path.min() * 1.1
mrange = mmax - mmin
pertick = mrange / 6
logpertick = math.log10(pertick)
print(logpertick)
intpertick = int(logpertick)
print(intpertick)
lpt_frac = logpertick - intpertick
# If the log is closer to .5, then we'll use 5x.
if lpt_frac > 0.3:
    step = 10**int(intpertick) * 5
else:
    step = 10**int(intpertick)
```

Comment: That's great and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Tim!!

Comment: Do you have a reference where I can find it in the source code by any chance?

Comment: This is a deep rabbit hole.  That's a very generic library.  I believe it's in https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py , but there are a lot of pieces.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a deep rabbit hole. Thanks for the link. This will defiently expose my Python skills but I've posted my solution below in case it could be helpful. I've tested it and it seems to do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

In case something is looking for an answer to my question above, here is my solution

```
   def Yticks(vals,bins):
        
        nbins=bins
        vmin = min(vals)
        vmax = max(vals)
        
        def scale_range(vmin, vmax, n=1, threshold=100):
            dv = abs(vmax - vmin)  # > 0 as nonsingular is called before.
            meanv = (vmax + vmin) / 2
            if abs(meanv) / dv < threshold:
                offset = 0
            else:
                offset = math.copysign(10 ** (math.log10(abs(meanv)) // 1), meanv)
            scale = 10 ** (math.log10(dv / n) // 1)
            return scale, offset
        
        
        def closeto(ms, edge,offset1):
            # Allow more slop when the offset is large compared to the step.
            if offset1 > 0:
                digits = np.log10(offset1 / step)
                tol = max(1e-10, 10 ** (digits - 12))
                tol = min(0.4999, tol)
            else:
                tol = 1e-10
            return abs(ms - edge) < tol
        
        def le(x):
            """Return the largest n: n*step <= x."""
            d, m = divmod(x, step)
            if closeto(m / step, 1,offset):
                return d + 1
            return d
        
        def ge(x):
            """Return the smallest n: n*step >= x."""
            d, m = divmod(x, step)
            if closeto(m / step, 0,offset):
                return d
            return d + 1
            
    
        steps = np.array([1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10])
        extended_steps = np.concatenate([0.1 * steps[:-1], steps, [10 * steps[1]]])
        
    
        scale, offset = scale_range(vmin, vmax, nbins)
        _vmin = vmin - offset
        _vmax = vmax - offset
        raw_step = (_vmax - _vmin) / nbins
        steps = extended_steps * scale
        igood = (steps < 1) | (np.abs(steps - np.round(steps)) < 0.001)
        istep = np.nonzero(steps >= raw_step)[0][0]
        
        
        for istep in range(istep, len(steps)):
                step = steps[istep]
                best_vmin = (_vmin // step) * step
                best_vmax = best_vmin + step * nbins
                if best_vmax >= _vmax:
                    break
                
        if np.floor(_vmax) - np.ceil(_vmin) >= 10 - 1:
            step = max(1, step)
            best_vmin = (_vmin // step) * step
            
            
            
        low = le(_vmin - best_vmin)
        high = ge(_vmax - best_vmin)
        
        ticks = np.arange(low, high + 1) * step + best_vmin
        nticks = ((ticks <= _vmax) & (ticks >= _vmin)).sum()
        
        yticks = ticks + offset
        return yticks
```